# How to display a leading zeros for number in wx.SpinCtrl?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

What's the best way to dispay leading zeros for number in wx.SpinCtrl?

I've created SpinCtrl:

```
self.MySpin = wx.SpinCtrl(self, min=1, max=100)
```

and i want that displaying 002, 003... 012 etc
when i press up button in this spin

How I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to do this, you'd need to use `wxSpinButton` bound to a `wxTextCtrl` manually.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's supported by wxPython. You would have to roll your own widget or modify an existing one. I would look at FloatSpin since it is pure Python. It would be a lot easier to hack than wx.SpinCtrl since SpinCtrl is a wrapped C++ widget.

Answer (score 0):

For solving my problem i've changed widget wx.SpinCtrl to wx.SpinButton (as recommend user VZ. in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17616095/2560258)) and i've created new class `LeadingSpinButton` inherited from wx.SpinButton and add `GetLeadingValue` method, `leading_width` and `leading_char` attributes.

```
class LeadingSpinButton(wx.SpinButton):

    def __init__(self, parent, style, leading_width=0, leading_char='0'):
        wx.SpinButton.__init__(self, parent=parent, style=style)
        self.leading_width = leading_width
        self.leading_char = leading_char

    def GetLeadingValue(self):
        """GetLeadingValue(self) -> str"""
        value = str(self.GetValue())
        value = value.rjust(self.leading_width, self.leading_char)
        return value
```

How is my solution?